# Moving the image according to the Button click

Tags: android

I used four buttons (Up,down,Left,Right) and also i have image. I have to move the image accordingly when i press UP button i should move image in upward direction and when i press left similarly remaining both direction it should move image in left direction.I have used onclick listener and then i am trying to move image using X,Y co-ordinates.I don't how take X,Y co-ordinates.

**Here is the code.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button up,left,right,down; 

         ImageView i1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            left=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

            right=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

            down=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

            i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            up.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"UP",5000).show();  

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 

        i1.getLayoutParams();

        int x = (int)getRawx();

        int y = (int)getRawY();

        mParams.leftMargin = x-50;

        mParams.topMargin = y-50;

       i1.setLayoutParams(mParams);


    }

}
```

HI,
    I have updated code below please check it.

package com.example.motion;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button up,left,right,down; 
ImageView i1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    left=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    right=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    down=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    up.setOnClickListener(this);
    down.setOnClickListener(this);
    left.setOnClickListener(this);
    right.setOnClickListener(this);
}



public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"UP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
        i1.getLayoutParams();
        mParams.topMargin -= 20;
        i1.setLayoutParams(mParams);
        break;
        }


    case R.id.button4:
           {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"DOWN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
                i1.getLayoutParams();
                mParams.topMargin += 20;
                i1.setLayoutParams(mParams);
                break; 
           }


    case R.id.button2:
               {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"LEFT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
                i1.getLayoutParams();
                mParams.leftMargin -= 20;
                i1.setLayoutParams(mParams);    
                break;  
               }

    case R.id.button3:
               {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"RIGHT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
            i1.getLayoutParams();
            mParams.leftMargin += 20;
            i1.setLayoutParams(mParams);
            break;
               }


}
    }
 }
```

Comment: any Body please reply

Comment: Tell where i am going wrong is this possible to move image using onclick listener

Comment: why are you changing x when pressing up button? shouldn't be only y to change?

Comment: ok ok but i getting error at int x=(int) getRawX(); which method should i call

Comment: is my logic correct i have getting what is the alternative

Comment: I posted an answer, try with that I hope it will help

Comment: SANJEEVREDDY I have also the same requirement.Used your and @lelloman  code but its not working. Can you help me please?

Comment: Ok ok i will post whole code you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `(int)getRawx();` and `(int)getRawy();`, you are calling this methods on Activity and I'm not so sure you really need those values.

you could try:

```
mParams.leftMargin += 50;
```

or

```
int x = mParams.leftMargin;
mParams.leftMargin = x + 50
```

Comment: Used the above code but its not working. Can you guys help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Subrat the first thing I would try is changing margins in the xml layout and see if you can move the image there, just to be sure that the problem is inside onClick and not in the layout arrangement

Comment: Hello Subrat, I have updated the the answer check it and reply me