# Android image moving on button click

Tags: android, image, button, move

bee to android programming and learning things.

i have the following code with me and what i need is to move only two selected images when button click happen
first user will select two images
then on button click they will move to left direction

here is my code

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imLady"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="238dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lady"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>


     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imLady2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="238dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lady"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

      <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/imLady3"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="238dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lady"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>


      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Move" />
```

looking forward for suggestions,solutions from u guys:) regards

Comment: So what have you tried so far? You cannot expect anyone to just post the complete solution to your problem. This site is only here to help you figure out how to get their on your own or fix any errors you might encounter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moving-the-image-according-to-the-button-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849010/moving-the-image-according-to-the-button-click)

Comment: Mr Xaver, its my mistake that i didnt put my activity code, and im thanks you show me that by telling these thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to setAnimations to your ImageViews in `onClick()` function of Button

```
ImageView v1,v2;
 Button b;
TranslateAnimation ta1,ta2;
...
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstances);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);
    ...
    initiate and refer button and imageviews
    ...
    ta1=new TranslateAnimation(fromx,tox,fromy,toy);
    ta1.setDuration(1000); //1 second

    ta2=new TranslateAnimation(fromx,tox,fromy,toy);
    ta2.setDuration(1000); //1 second

     b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
     @override
     public void onClick(View arg0)
     {
     v1.startAnimation(ta1);
     v2.startAnimation(ta2);
     }
     });


  }
```

refer to TranslateAnimation Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

Comment: thanks rajan. i got the idea , i know how to move the images but what i wanted is first user should select two images then after that only button clcik should happen.