# How to swap 2 or more ImageView when button clicked

Tags: java, android, xml

I was trying to implement the following design and the animation but non of the Android development group or Anyone can't able to help me. I badly need help.

I have seen this but won't understand[Animated swap position of two buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599828/android-image-moving-on-button-click)

This is what I actually want to do.
[image: I want to design like this one. I don't know how the bar and the pointer made to point 2 objects]

This is what I did:
[image: I used here ImageView to work with]
[image: And wants to swap objects]

Here XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"

        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"

        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**What I did:**
I tried using an MPAndroidChart for bar which will be handled. Shortly, I'm trying to create an algorithm visualizer project but I didn't find any good resource so that bar could be created and handled efficiently and easily. Badly I didn't even find any resource except customview on how he implemented It's completely hard to understand.

**What I expect:**
I want to know how to design that bar and how I can swap those bar or bars when the button clicks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: let me first get this straight, do you want your custom images to swap, or do you want the bars in the bar chart to swap?

Comment: Ofcourse. I want custom images to swap.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is late, but still I'm trying to answer your question.

You can use textView instead of imageView. In textView, you can simply add random background color and set the height according to the number in the textView.

For swap image among imageViews,
Let's say you have two imageView with id iv1 and iv2. You can get the image of iv2 by `findViewById(R.id.iv2).getDrawable()` and then set the drawable image to iv1.

Comment: I already solved this problem using placeholder + imageview. Swapping image too easy with placeholder you can call this a simple animation. If you want to see my application live -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sakibxhossain.gridlayout_practice

All the animation I did using placeholder.